# How to enable remote access to elasticsearch - elasticsearch.yml - network.host

Tags: elasticsearch, centos7

I've just setup elasticsearch on a vanilla minimal CentOS 7 server.

It's working:

```
curl localhost:9200
{
 "name" : "Superia",
 "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
 "version" : {
  "number" : "5.0.0-alpha4",
"build_hash" : "3f5b994",
"build_date" : "2016-06-27T16:23:46.861Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "6.1.0"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I've read you must update /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and set the network.host to a value to get it working but it fails if I make any changes to it.

Has anyone got this version working over the network?  If so please could you paste your elasticsearch.yml file here so I can check spacing and values etc?

Answer (score 0):

In order to protect your ES instance, it's best not to bind to a publicly available IP.

What I'd recommend, is that you communicate with the remote ES instance through an SSH tunnel. If you add the following to your `.ssh/config` file...

```
Host some-alias-you-can-remember
  Hostname 8.8.8.8 # (put the IP address of your CentOS box here)
  Port 22 # (the SSH port on which the centos box listens)
  User yourUserName # (on the CentOS box)
  LocalForward 9200 localhost:9200
```

... you can access the remote instance on `localhost:9200`.

Comment: I've just realised the new Kibana allows you to import csv data in to elastic so actually I don't need external access anymore.